# Nokia Asha SDK: Glitch in List component when used with TextField on the same Form

Tags: list, lwuit, nokia

I'm a bit stuck with strange behaviour of List component in Asha SDK. What I'm doing is using TextField and List on the same form. Just a TextField and a List on BoxLayout, with no relationship. The problem is - focusing on TextField seems to trigger creation of another List component which is exact copy of original one, but displays just one item. You can see it in

[image: List with focused TextForm image]

- large green border marks 2 horizontal row delimiters - first one belongs to original List, second one seems to belong to that new fake List
- small green border marks little vertical scroll bar which works for new fake List. Original List uses big scroll bar, you can see it on the right.
- 'Item 9' on provided image belongs to fake List, 'Item 8' - to original one.

And this image shows how List is rendered when TextField is non-focused. Everything there seems to be correct:

[image: this image]

Could you please advise is there any way to solve this glitch? Is it possible to tweak it somehow with LookAndFeel? I really don't need that fake List.
By the way, on Nokia SDK 2 (S40) there is no such glitch, everything works as expected.

P.S. What I'm trying to implement is Autocomplete TextField. I'm using [this article](http://codenameone.blogspot.ru/2008/06/lightweight-text-input-in-lwuit.html) for that. If there is any other way to do so for Asha SDK, please share.

Comment: Can you share your code? It will be useful.